# Postgres: Extract the last substring in a string

Tags: regex, postgresql, position, substring

I've got a string like

```
We would like to approve your call, however you have been denied because of reasons
```

I want to extract the **last** appearance of either "approve your call" or "have been denied" on the principal that that indicates whether it was approved or declined. I have to use the specific substrings since this is based on a form, not just "approve" and "decline".

My idea was to use a regexp_match to pull out all appearances then grabbing the last row, however there's no way to get the last row from the result of regexp_match.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Postgres 9.4+, you can use [`WITH ORDINALITY`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/queries-table-expressions.html#QUERIES-TABLEFUNCTIONS) to identify the last row in the `regexp_matches` result:

```
SELECT m
FROM regexp_matches('abc', '.', 'g') WITH ORDINALITY r(m,n)
ORDER BY n DESC
LIMIT 1
```

On older versions, you can do this with a [window function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-window.html)  (though it does rely on the natural ordering of the result set, which is generally best avoided):

```
SELECT last_value(m) OVER ()
FROM regexp_matches('abc', '.', 'g') r(m)
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: Ah! that window function will work. Based on testing the natural_ordering of regexp_matches appears to be the lexical ordering, so I think that will be a good fix